# How to generate one report from different jobs in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to mail one report from pipeline. Pipeline executing different jobs each of which have reports. I'm looking at "Snippet Generator" but can't set multiply report collection

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing like this available (tests aggregator is not maintained, open bug for this in JIRA since 2016). What you could do is copy the reports as artifacts to upsteam, but maybe those should be stages instead of separate jobs?

Comment: you actually can archive each logfile in each job after it runs and then you can attahced in the email from the main job. If you need an example let me know

Comment: @mbn217 yes, if it possible please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So first let assume you have job A job B and Job C (that calls job A and Job B)

In each Job A and Job B you need to archive their log file , so you will need to add this script into your pipeline:

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)
def bld = job.getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)=
//use the method that suits you
bld.getLog(100) //number of lines to read
bld.getLogFile()
bld.getLogReader()
```

Now that your logs are being archived in each of the jobs , you can go to Job C at the post stage and use copyArtifact plugin to copy the archived logs 
example:

```
//copyArtifacts filter: 'logs.log', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'pathtoyourjob/job A', selector: lastSuccessful(), target: 'temp1' 

//copyArtifacts filter: 'logs.log', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'pathtoyourjob/job B', selector: lastSuccessful(), target: 'temp1'
```

This is the only workaround I was able to use before.
Hope it helps!